# Is there an SE mechanism to deal with serial comment deletions by mods/whoever?

Tags: discussion, support

So I have this meta question - [This SE site doesn't have a chance with the current users and mods, how does this get fixed?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/this-se-site-doesnt-have-a-chance-with-the-current-users-and-mods-how-does-thi)

**Reference Points:**

1. It is still unresolved as there are a wide variety of examples still with wrong answers heavily upvoted - supported by the site's mods.   And those questions have right answer(s) downvoted and unsupported by the site's mods.
2. In the meta question I mention the serial downvotes I received.  I am a long-time SE member and top on a few sites.  I am smart enough to recognize serial voting.   I am sure most long-time SE users are.
3. I have people and examples of testing serial voting.   Simply if you vote on enough things the system does not catch this behavior.
4. This serial voting was not just downvoting my answers but often included writing an answer on their own that was very close to mine, followed by quick upvotes - yes Sports SE is easy to see this when most questions unless they are a network question receive very little views or votes.   There was a defined pattern and most of the "new" answers were written and/or comments by a small group of users including mods.   (SE isn't about knowledge it is a game score basically)

**Question at hand:**

So above was some history and points of reference.   Now based on my meta question at the top and the meta question itself...   User comments that supported or added to my answers including my own were deleted from multiple questions.   No comments supporting the other answers were deleted, none of these were "discussions", and negative comments (mainly by the mods) were kept.

What is funny is the mods kept comments that were outdated.   Example is asking for a reference and then keeping the comment once reference was given, yet deleting other comments that added to the answer.

**So is there a mechanism or check to make sure there is not serial or deceptive comment deletion?**

Comment: As an addition: a) there are times the mods take a back and forth comment discussion to a chatroom. That's fine, but by doing so they also remove any existing comments there which means any comment regarding the post itself and not the discussion that caused the move to chat room is also removed. b) SE itself (not sport related) doesn't have any sort of notification when a comment is deleted. So you end up having random comments out of context when users (usually mods that point something out) remove their comments.

Comment: @alamoot I think that is a bit different than what Coach-D is asking here; you're welcome to ask a separate question about that if you want.  Briefly, it is possible to move only selected comments to a chat, and sometimes mods will do that, but it's not always easy to do, and again comments are intended to be ephemeral.

Comment: Funny that I have a well written question with tons of history and examples and it gets downvoted.     Just a word (since you can't downvote a comment) for the mods and SE staff - categorically downvoting all meta things that question mod behavior only makes you look corrupt and at fault.   It is not a good look for the site and makes people think it is run like a monarchy.  This is probably why SE has had a hard time entering enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

Comment deletion by moderators can be viewed by moderators (or above, of course).  However, for the most part comments are *always* subject to arbitrary deletion; they are not intended to persist nor to contain important information.

If you are concerned about a specific moderator action, please contact the CMs using the Contact link on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Joe - never had an issue with you and I understand your answer.   However my account was just suspended for months basically for calling specific mods out for this.   So how does one prove what they cannot see or they have access to?   So based on your answer - any mod, can abuse the system and basically harass a user they do not like by allowing/deleting comments without much view or ability for the user to do anything?   And SE has nothing automated to ever check if a mod is deleting more comments from a user or their answers?

Comment: To further this in the meta question I referenced above - inside the question I mention comments agreeing with me by others... these are all gone now.   Why?  (we know why) And I wrote enough here to cover any excuses that anyone can make.

Comment: @Coach-D Anything you have questions with on this you really should take up with the CMs.  Mods are expected to follow standards of conduct, just as users are (more of them), and mod violations are taken seriously.  I don't know what SE has automated-wise, but they wouldn't communicate that really in any event; but I doubt they do, as this isn't something that occurs regularly, it would be a case by case thing.

Comment: That is funny that you mention that.   As soon as I wrote the meta question several concerned mods and SE staff members reached out and asked me for examples <===== sarcasm.....